# Fetch record until sum is equal to a certain no

Tags: postgresql

The below query is working just fine for me but what i want is that if so_far is something like 297 and next some_num_field is 4 then the query  will return records up to sum of 297. In such a situation it should get next row order by created_at whose some_num_field value is less <= 3 (300-297)

```
WITH eligible as (
    select id, name, some_num_field,
        sum(some_num_field) over (ORDER BY created_at) as so_far
    from test
)

SELECT *
FROM eligible
WHERE so_far <= 300
```

Comment: Your query already seems to be doing what you want.  What is the problem?

Comment: Suppose at sum 297 next value to add is 4, it should skip this and select next row whose value is less than 4 and so on

Comment: It might be helpful if you add to your question why you want this business logic, as it seems a bit unusual.